# Select date for today

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

Table: id, confess, user_ip, time, url, loves, hate

Time is like 1413040760

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM confessions where time >= unix_timestamp(curdate() + interval 1 day)") or die(mysql_error());
```

I need the best `confess` of day `order by loves limit 1`. This show my only blank, no results.

Answer (score 2):

You're querying records that happened later than one day from now - i.e., in the future. Presumably, you don't have any records like that. You can change the `+ interval 1 day` to `- interval 1 day` in order to get records that occurred up to 1 day **ago**.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM confessions where time >= unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day)") or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comment, yes, it's possible to sort by `loves - hates` - just slap on an `order by` clause:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * " .
                 "FROM confessions " .
                 "WHERE time >= unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day) " .
                 "ORDER BY (loves - hates) DESC" ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works , is it possible to LOVES - HATES and sort by that number for today?  sorry for my bad english

Comment: `SELECT *, (loves - hates) AS total [...] ORDER BY total DESC`